# How to save xmpp chat history in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am trying to build an application where I need to save the xmpp ejabberd chat history in mysql database using PHP. I am using the ubuntu system and my php version is 5.5.9 and mysql version is 5.5.47

I got [this](http://www.dp.uz.gov.ua/o.palij/mod_logdb/) link, but I can not understand how can I save the chat history in mysql.

So if any one has saved the chat history in mysql using ejabberd "mod_logdb" modules then please explain me how can I do it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources and tutorials is off-topic on SO. Remove that bit from your question or it will be put on hold until you comply.

Comment: @NSNoob - as per your suggestion, I edited my question. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to configure standard ejabberd [mod_mam](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmam) to save message in MySQL. MySQL configuration is described in ejabberd guide: [Using ejabberd with MySQL](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/databases/mysql/)